# Spring 4 & Hibernate 5 validator messageSource does not work

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I can't get use to work hibernate validation 5.1.0.Final with Spring MVC 4.2.5.RELEASE.

My WebConfig:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor getValidationPostProcessor(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor processor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        processor.setValidator(validator);
        return processor;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }
    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor l = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        l.setParamName("lang");
        return l;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver s = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        s.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return s;
    }
```

I have an ExceptionHanlder which gets validation messages and push it back as a json:

```
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationError handleConstraintViolation(final ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        ValidationError v = new ValidationError();

        exception.getConstraintViolations().forEach(violation -> {
                v.addError(violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), violation.getMessage());
        });
        logger.warn(exception, exception);
        return v;
    }
```

I have 3 files in src/main/resources/i18n/: messages_en_EN.properties, messages_pl_PL.properties, messages.properties. 
My model class with validation has one validated parameter:

```
    @Column(name = "VALUE_", nullable = false)
    @Email(message = "{Email.contractorContactEmail.value}")
    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.contractorContactEmail.value}")
    private String value;
```

What I see is that hibernate validator look into classpath:ValidationMessages properties not into my spring message source. It may be ok for me but Hibernate does not want to translate those messages - locale is always server default. What am I doing wrong?? How can I fix it?

PS. In controller I use @org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated.

PS2. I am sure that my messageSource is working correctly because if I add this code into ExceptionHandler it translates perfectly but I know that it is bad practice.

```
exception.getConstraintViolations().forEach(violation -> {
            String messageTemplate = violation.getMessageTemplate();
            if (messageTemplate.startsWith("{") && messageTemplate.endsWith("}")) {
                String key = StringUtils.substring(messageTemplate, 1, messageTemplate.length() - 1);
                v.addError(violation.getPropertyPath().toString(), messageSource.getMessage(key, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can tell you right away, judging from your configuration, your messages are in the wrong place - you've configured the message source to look at `i18/messages` but your messages are in the classpath root. So, your message source definition should look like:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return messageSource;
}
```

Aside from that, the rest of the configuration looks pretty much okay. I'm  guessing that you're using the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class?

**EDIT:**
For future reader's reference, the issue was not configuration-related, JPA entity was missing a `@Valid` annotation on a `@OneToMany` field so controller-level validation failed to pick it up and Hibernate's JPA validator used default messages.

Comment: Ops sorry my mistake. My messages are in src/main/resources/i18n.

Comment: I am fighting with it 3 days long and can't configure it... I am thinking if it may be an issue with integration between spring 4 and hibernate validator 5? I am using jboss as web application server.. Maybe it may help? Maybe I am missing some jars? I have no idea..

Comment: No, if your messages are configured correctly then I guess that MVC did not pick up the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` correctly. Can you try adding an `@Autowired private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;` field into your configuration class and returning the field value from `getValidator()`?

Comment: And yes I am using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class. Yes I tried to autowire LocalValidatorFactoryBean in ExceptionHandling class and it returns the bean from configuration. Also locale chaning works because LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() returns correct value.

Comment: Do You know any entry point where I can debug hibernate to see what may be the issue?

Comment: I meant adding the autowired field into your configuration class, see my updated answer. `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` should be a good place to start, Spring should automatically configure its own bean once it sees Hibernate's bean validator on the classpath

Comment: The main issue your experiencing is that your validator isn't using the correct message interpolator - it's using the default instead of the Spring's message source one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118787/discussion-between-milos-milivojevic-and-gazeciarz).